# What is the correct return from payment provider URL?

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, omnipay, swipehq

I'm developing a payment plugin for SwipeHQ (a New Zealand based online credit card processor) for my clients Drupal website running CiviCRM.

Currently a user will make a purchase and be redirected to the correct payment provider page, but is currently (incorrectly) being redirected to the IPN notification page on completion. The IPN end point should be used by the payment provider to notify the server of success or otherwise, but when the client is redirected here none of this information yet exists so it throws an exception. How do I instead redirect to the completion page ("hi your purchase is successful pending payment") - I have tried passing the URL in the format

```
civicrm/event/register?_qf_Confirm_display=true&e436769547477d10db6253a97538b92a_7705
But it complains about not being able to find the id..
```

I guess what I'm asking is, is there an easy way, given a transaction id or something similar (which I can hake the payment provider pass back to me) I can close the users current transaction?

Answer (score 2):

welcome to CiviCRM - we had some communications with a potential client who had an in-house developer that did some work on SwipeHQ. Suggest you try getting in touch with him via this [question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/how-to-detect-handle-card-failure-from-payment-providers-callback-url?sem=2) or give me a buzz and I will put you in touch if that is helpful. Adding a SwipeHQ tag

Comment: Thank you, will leave a note on his question but if you could help me get in touch also, that would be great!

Edit: I cant actually comment as Ive only just joined this exchange - would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like a comment to me ;-). Flick me a request via fuzion.co.nz and i will pass it on to him

Comment: oh may be you can't comment on someone elses question. - will +1 your comment to me in case that helps

Comment: I've added a proposed approach on that question, hope it helps this too.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for that comment, the issue is Im not sure how to actually access the payment "thanks"/"failed" pages - as in what url, parameters etc I actually need. Currently I get a "id not found" error whenever I try to redirect there